# How to return an array to an excel spreadsheet?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to print an array to a spreadsheet using a VBA function. (Similar to how LINEST returns an array). However, my function does not seem to like to be assigned to an array and then won't print it.

Here is a bit of the code:

```
 Public Function Volume(x As Double, xmax As Double, Flows As Range) As Double()

 dim Y4(9) As Double

 'A bunch of stuff which eventually fills Y4

 Volume = Y4

 End Function
```

Resources are welcome too, but I was unable to find an answer after a fairly long search.

Comment: array formulas have to be entered with Ctrl + Shift + Enter

Comment: And don't forget that your array is probably being declared as `0 To 9`, so (a) the first cell will be receiving the value of `Y4(0)` and (b) you will need to select 10 columns in the same row to receive all the 10 values being returned

Comment: Your method **IS** returning an array. (I just filled the array with serial numbers).  There is something wrong with either the *bunch of stuff* or in the manner in which you are testing your function.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, Y4 is full of values (checked using message boxes), I have selected ten spaces clicked F2 the ctrl-shift-enter but it's printing a bunch of zeroes rather than the values stored in Y4.

Comment: Were the ten cells you selected in a single Row?  Single Column? or mixed? With a 1D array, you will need to select the ten cells in a single **ROW**

Comment: Yup, they're 10 in a row, also the first value is non zero so that should get printed in either case?

Comment: You will need to provide more information then, as it works as expected here. How do you know Y4 is full of values?  What happens if you use the INDEX function to access the various values?

Answer (score 0):

Excel needs a two-dimensional array (Rows, Columns) even if you're only returning one column. SO this works:

```
Public Function Volume(x As Double, xmax As Double, Flows As Range) As Double()
    Dim lCt As Long
    Dim Y4(1 To 10, 1 To 1) As Double

    'A bunch of stuff which eventually fills Y4
    For lCt = 1 To 10
        Y4(lCt, 1) = Rnd()
    Next
    Volume = Y4

End Function
```

Comment: You do not need a 2-D array - but see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/returningarraysfromvba.aspx under "Orienting an array"

Comment: Hmm, not the best answer I ever posted I guess :-)

Comment: I'm constantly having to remind myself how that works (which is why i had that link handy...)   I sometimes use a 2-D array as you show, because it's easier to visualize how it "fits" in the return range.